# Can I set a default imported picture width in Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word, automation

**Background:**
If I drag an image into a Word 2016 doc, a sufficiently large image is automatically scaled to fit within the left and right margins, and a smaller image is scaled to a width proportional to its horizontal pixel count.

**Question:**
Is there a way that I can set a default imported/dragged-in image width to, say, 4.0", so I don't have to manually resize them?

I would prefer not to involve scripts or macros, though if there is no other way, I'll take what I can get.

(I am aware of the F4 repeat function, but this is also a hassle, since I often have to bring dozens of images into a document.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No.

Unless the images you are dragging or inserting into the document are already sized the way you want them, then you have to resize them once they are into the document. Resizing after insertion can be done with a macro.